# Instantiating gameObject based on Type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So basically I'm struggling with a problem and was hoping someone here could point me in the right direction.

Im randomly generating Items, and am trying to instantiate said items, the only problem is while I'm able to instantiate the parent item, I won't know up front if the generated item will be a "weapon/armor" etc, which are all inherited children of Item. So I am able to get the Type of the generated item, but am having trouble converting that Type back to said Script/Object to be instantiated.

For example :
Item > Weapon > Sword.
I am able to generate a sword, and get the type of the sword, however I am unable to instantiate a sword, because I only have the Type and not an actual Sword.

Since my Sword class has data loaded during it's Start method, then Weapon, then Item, I cannot just instantiate an Item and know it's a sword.
Perhaps I'm doing this all wrong.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: 1) Factories ("make me a thing") and 2) Item Registries ("find me the pattern for a thing I know the name of").

Comment: Thank you! I'm reading on factories right now. Do you have any simple examples or links?

Comment: @Draco18s I'm not sure how to mark your comment as a great answer, but thank you very much. Teaching to fish is very important in this field and I'm learning a lot, I just didn't know where to begin. Factories look great!

Comment: @Holden take a look into scriptable objects you can create a database and then have the lookup pretty quickly. SO's have been around for awhile and they are very nice for this particular situation.

Comment: @LevonRavel Thanks! I will do some reading on these as well =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a weapons `enum`

```
public enum WeaponType {sword, crossbow, q36SpaceModulator }
```

Use that to tell your [factory (@Draco18s comment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53403685/instantiating-gameobject-based-on-type#comment93682407_53403685) what to build - methods for creating weapons in this case.

```
public class WeaponFactory {
    public Weapon Create (WeaponType thisWeapon) {
       Weapon newWeapon; 

       switch (thisWeapon) {
          case WeaponType.sword :
             newWeapon = BuildSword();
             break;

          case WeaponType.crossbow:
             newWeapon = BuildCrossbow();
             break;

          // and so on...
          default:  // we don't have whatever-you-asked-for
       }

       return newWeapon;
    }

    private Weapon BuildSword() { return new Sword(); }

}

// somewhere in code...
// you may have other parameters for particular weapon attributes
var sword = royalArmory.Create(Weapon.sword);
```

Comment: I really like this concept, however at time of needing to create a weapon, I only know the Type. I'm not sure how to convert the Type of the Weapon into the WeaponType enum value.

Comment: 1) research `Type` class in MSDN. "Name" is in there somewhere. And `enum` too. Find out what `ToString` does. 2) I don't understand why/how you only have a `Type` object. How does the code know the `Type` in the first place? What does the UI communicate to the program?

Comment: I honestly probably did it wrong to start, but basically i'm trying to randomly generate everything I can. When I click "open chest" I randomly generate an Item there, and then determine if its a weapon, armor, boots, etc, and then what type of weapon. That's where I ended up with the Type so that I can see which type it is.

Comment: but what is  "Type"? Sure it represents a concrete something in your application domain. But as coded is it a C# Type class object or merely a string? You always capitalize it - is it a class you invented? "I have the Type" means what? There's an object of some class (what class?) that has a property called "type" that is a string set to the value "sword"? Some code might be helpful.

Comment: Just Generic Type. I haven't had to use it much prior to this so it's been a hill to climb over.
I think I have figured that issue out, however now I"m running into the problem that when I return a newWeapon, the start method in Unity doesn't run unless it's in a gameObject so I need to figure out how to "initialize" that newWeapon upon creation.

Comment: `Enum` may not be a sufficient means of providing information to the factory, but it works here. (For example, Minecraft uses registry names, which are essentially strings: a mod ID (Minecraft's mod ID is "minecraft") and the item name, which allows multiple mods to supply copper ingots, etc)

Comment: @Draco18s, agreed "may not be sufficient", in fact is often the case. FYI, @Holden, this `enum` "identifier" can one property in an object carrying lots of info for instantiating a given object. Another use case, in lieu of many, many sub classes, a "what am i" property implemented using an `enum`. But its viability depends on the overall design. Generally `enum`s are fabulous for several technical and practical reasons and I use them as often as I can.